# ExtJS 4. Trying to get the MVC structure working

Tags: model, extjs4

I'm including a model from within a store like this:

```
Ext.define('EZMail.store.unProcessedStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'EZMail.model.EmailDir',
    model: 'EZMail.model.EmailDir',
    constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        storeId: 'unProcessedStore',
        autoLoad:true,
        proxy: {
//... more config
```

And the model couldn't be simpler:

```
Ext.define('EZmail.model.EmailDir', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [ 'emailDir' ],
});
```

But I'm getting this error in Developer Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
(anonymous function)
Ext.ClassManager.instantiateext-all-debug.js:3948
(anonymous function)ext-all-debug.js:1555
Ext.define.getStoreext-all-debug.js:39754
(anonymous function)ext-all-debug.js:1548
(anonymous function)ext-all-debug.js:19698
Ext.Array.eachext-all-debug.js:953
Ext.define.createGettersext-all-debug.js:19684
Ext.define.constructorext-all-debug.js:19668
Base.callParentext-all-debug.js:2891
Ext.define.constructorext-all-debug.js:39669
Ext.Class.newClassext-all-debug.js:3188
(anonymous function)
Ext.ClassManager.instantiateext-all-debug.js:3948
(anonymous function)ext-all-debug.js:1555
(anonymous function)ext-all-debug.js:5693
isEventext-all-debug.js:10516
call
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Is your constructor even get called? Add console.log before the first line inside constructor to see whether it's something in your code, or just the way you're defining classes.

Comment: console.log gets fired if I put it before the constructor. BTW, That error message only appears once I include the model.

Comment: How exactly it happens? Your constructor is inside class definition. Where do you put console.log _before_ it? btw, what's the name of the file and full path with store definition? I see that you have first letter in lower case for class name 'unPro...'. Usually you need to have last word in the class name be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make it so complicated.
Store definition:

```
Ext.define('My.store.Requests', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'My.model.Request',
    autoLoad: false,
    remoteSort: true,
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'request/list.json',
        //override default param names
        startParam : "offset",
        limitParam :"max",
        sortParam : "sort",
        simpleSortMode:true,//required for directionParam to be used
        directionParam : "order",
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }

    },
    pageSize: 25
});
```

p.s. your model has an extra trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

Your model reference in the store doesn't need the fully qualified path.  Just use the the model's name.